# Why is Firefox displaying the same CSS differently on a link<a> and a <input type=submit>?

Tags: css

Kind of come up a against a weird problem...

Here is my css for a button:

```
a.cta-btn-green { 
    color:#fff !important; 
    font-size:14px !important; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    text-shadow: #060 1px 1px 1px; 
    background-color:#329122; 
    padding:5px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius:14px; 
    -webkit-border-radius:14px; 
    text-decoration:none;
    float:right;
    border:0;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    cursor:pointer;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(100% 100% 90deg, #307d23, #4ac236); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#4ac236), to(#307d23));
}


input.cta-btn-green { 
    color:#fff !important; 
    font-size:14px !important; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    text-shadow: #060 1px 1px 1px; 
    background-color:#329122; 
    padding:5px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius:14px; 
    -webkit-border-radius:14px; 
    text-decoration:none;
    float:right;
    border:0;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    cursor:pointer;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(100% 100% 90deg, #307d23, #4ac236); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#4ac236), to(#307d23));
}
```

Both CSS classes are the same, but one is applied to `<a>` and the other is applied to `<input type="submit" />` ...The effect is that Firefox is giving the `input.cta-btn-green` greater height than `a.cta-btn-green` ?

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is the font higher or the whole element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you tell your `a` and `input` to `display:block` then you will be able to set specific heights and thus make them the same.

so add the following lines to both rules:

```
display:block;
height:20px; /*adjust this as needed*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly setting the `height` and `line-height` for each rule.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's because you're just setting the font height - the `<input>` element afaik also has the typical button-border which the `<a>` element doesn't have.